# Error while connecting to SQL Server with Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, devops, sql-server-2019, connectivity

I'm facing an issue while connecting to my SQL Server with a Azure DevOps pipeline.

The pipeline starts a web service on localhost. The web service should connect to the SQL server

```
Connection string='DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=tcp:\*\*\***-DRIVE-\\SQLEXPRESS;PORT=1433;DATABASE=EmailContactDB;UID=\*\*\*;PWD=\*\*\*;'
```

I'm getting this error:

> {"error":"('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
> Driver][DBNETLIB]Specified SQL server not found. (6)
> (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
> Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (11001); [08001]
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute
> (0)')"}

This works when I use the web service locally.

I couldn't find any solutions online. I checked the connection options in SSMS they look fine. The remote connection checkbox is ticked.

All help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility it's a firewall blockage? i have been caught by this a couple of times when using Azure SQL services and Azure Devops. Azure devops uses a couple of IP ranges for outbound traffic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4